# Not getting spring security auto-generated login page

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am new to Spring Security I am doing a simple Sppring Security Program but m not getting spring security auto-generated login page.
This is my Controller

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView showMessage(
            @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
        mv.addObject("message", message);
        mv.addObject("name", name);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showIndex() {
        System.out.println("in index controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public ModelAndView showMessageAdmin() {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

This is my Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  

  </welcome-file-list>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

This is my Spring Security XML class

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"        
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>

      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="Hello" password="Pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

This is my dispatcher servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ge.web.Controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

for /admin i want to get Spring Security by default login page for authentication. But I am not getting it it is directly going to view how can i get it where I m wrong?
    Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

First fix you `web.xml`: You don't need to specify `/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml` in context param since the file is under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` which is default location for dispatcher servlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Then in your pring Security XML: Here you were missing `<form-login /><logout />` which is required to get default Login form.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"        
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="Admin" password="AdminPassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: It is directly redirecting to admin.jsp page default login page is not coming ....

Comment: Have you tried above settings? Copy and paste above files, it should work. If you still not getting login page then try this `<http use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />...`